# Is nested reference of URLs in sitemap.xml good or bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I am having thousands of URLs in the website, If I put all URLs in sitemap.xml it's getting too large in size. There is some suggestion to split those URLs into different files and referring in main sitemap.xml

eg

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.example.com/rootpages-sitemap.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.example.com/detailpages-sitemap.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
...
</sitemapindex>
```

And in the reference file detailpages-sitemap.xml defining URLs

```xml
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> 
<url>
<loc> https://www.example.com/detail/Universal-Studios-Hollywood/</loc>
</url>
.....
</urlset>
```

Is this is a better way to implement it or is there an even better method?

Comment: Sitemaps have almost nothing to do with SEO no matter how they are structured..   They can get Googlebot to crawl all your pages, but they don't factor into whether Google chooses to index your pages or not.  Sitemaps don't have anything to do with how well your pages rank.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to split the sitemap by your website structure, example category pages, product pages, blog, etc, this way you can easily debug it if anything goes wrong.

Limit a single sitemap to 50MB (uncompressed) and 50,000 URLs. If you have a larger file or more URLs, you will have to break your list into multiple sitemaps.

Make sure there isn't any duplicate or unnecessary URLs on the sitemap.